# How send NfcA command to the MIFARE card?

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I'm writing an Android application. I'm trying to send `NfcA` low-level commands (in my case: HALT and WAKE-UP) to my Mifare Plus S card. The `NfcA` tech is for "low-level" access to ISO 14443 Type A tags (i.e. the
proprietary protocol as mentioned in ISO 14443-3).

This is part of my code:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        UID = Utils.byteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID));
    }
    NfcA nfca = null;
    try {
        Log.e(TAG, "WakeUpCMD and HaltCMD");
        nfca = NfcA.get(tagFromIntent);
        nfca.connect();
        Short s = nfca.getSak();
        byte[] a = nfca.getAtqa();
        byte[] HaltCMD = {0x35, 0x30, 0x30,0x30, 0x00};
        byte[] WakeUpCMD = {0x35, 0x32, 0x00};
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            data = nfca.transceive(HaltCMD);
            length = data.length;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "HALT complete "+Utils.byteArrayToHexString(data));
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Tag is connected: "+nfca.isConnected());
        //Log.e(TAG, "Response from tag "+Utils.byteArrayToHexString(data));
        nfca.setTimeout(100);
        data = nfca.transceive(WakeUpCMD);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from tag"+Utils.byteArrayToHexString(data));
        nfca.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error when reading tag");

    }
}
```

**WAKE-UP** Command is sent by the PCD to put PICCs which have entered the `HALT` State back into the `READY`
State. They shall then participate in further anticollision and selection procedures.

```
|b7| |b6| |b5| |b4| |b3| |b2| |b1|

|1  |  | 0 |  | 1|  | 0|  | 0|  | 1|  | 0| {‘52’} = WAKE-UP
```

**HALT** Command consists of four bytes and shall be transmitted using the Standard Frame.
First bit transmitted

```
S | ‘50’ | ‘00’ | CRC_A | E
```

If the PICC responds with any modulation during a period of 1 ms after the end of the `HALT` Frame, this response shall be interpreted as 'not acknowledge'.

This is the descriptions of the two commands from ISO 14443-3 which I try to send to my card.

When I start my app, I get a "Tag Lost" Exception. Can you help me? What's wrong? How can I send these commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if you are converting the command codes into null-terminated ASCII character strings before sending them with `NfcA.transceive()`:

```
byte[] HaltCMD = {0x35, 0x30, 0x30,0x30, 0x00};
byte[] WakeUpCMD = {0x35, 0x32, 0x00};
```

- `0x35 0x30 0x30 0x30` gives `"5000"`
- `0x35 0x32` gives `"52"`

This does not make any sense as the commands (`50 00` for HLTA, and `52` for WUPA) are hexadecimal representations of the command values already.

For the HLTA command, you would therefore need to send `50 00`:

```
data = nfca.transceive(new byte[] { (byte)0x50, (byte)0x00 });
```

Note that S (start of communication), E (end of communication), and CRC_A will be automatically added by the NFC controller (or the NFC stack).

For the WUPA command, you could probably try to send `52`:

```
data = nfca.transceive(new byte[] { (byte)0x52 });
```

However, it is very likely that the NFC stack does not permit you to send 7-bit commands using the transceive method. Instead, the stack may automatically use this command value as one full byte and add a CRC_A.

### General note on sending ISO/IEC 14443-3 initialization and anti-collision commands

Sending such commands may or may not work (depending on the NFC stack implementation and the NFC controller). In general I would strongly recommend that you do **not** send such commands. Particularly the HLTA command will confuse the internal state keeping of the NFC stack on some devices and will lead to unexpected results. **Normally, you don't need to exchange such commands, as anti-collision, initialization and activation are handled automatically by the NFC device.**

Comment: Thanks you. These commands can help me to use my card without re-attachin (for example: when I always wear it in my mobile phone case and I need to use it ). I try to wake up my card, and then I hope, android app will find a new intent.